# Running executables on AKS containers

Tags: kubernetes, network-programming, containers, cloud, azure-aks

I want to measure network performance between two containers on AKS, and currently planning to use [NetPerfTest](https://github.com/microsoft/NetPerfTest#:%7E:text=Description%20NetPerfTest%20is%20a%20collection%20of%20tools%20used,performance%20statistics%20for%20diagnosis%20of%20networking%20performance%20issues.) by Microsoft. The main concern is running an executable on AKS containers. The current NPT is designed for VMs so I would need to tweak it for containers. For your reference, NPT creates cmdlets for sending/receiving traffic from one VM to another. After sending the traffics, it collects and logs the information to the host. My initial thought is to create three AKS Services with a container each, and use them as 1)orchestrator(Creating commands and telling two other containers to send/receive traffic & logging in the test result), 2) Sender 3) Receiver.

I'm assuming that I would need to figure out 1) running an executable on AKS containers 2) sending traffic from one container to another 3) logging in the data from the test into a container that the local user can access.

How can I implement this on AKS containers? I would appreciate any help with either designing the overall structure in general or structuring YAML files/dockerfiles. Thanks ahead!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use NPT over Container insights?

Comment: @PawełGrondal I just wanted to try for a project. Trying to measure the container network performance and log it.